# Enum : type { }; Какой тип стоит по умолчанию?

Tags: c++

В с++ 11 появилась такая возможность, как:

```
enum AnyEnum : int8_t {
    a = -1,
    b = 0,
    c = 1,
};
```

Какой тип устанавливается по умолчанию, не учитывая различных оптимизаторов? Раньше, если не ошибаюсь, устанавливался `int;`.

Т.е. что поставится на этапе компиляции, если не указать тип?

Comment: Очевидно, что так же, как и ранее -- `int`.

Можете сами легко проверить, печатая sizeof.

Comment: Как я могу быть уверенным, написав sizeof, что никакой оптимизатор не отработал?

Comment: @arukasa, sizeof это  размер памяти в байтах, который будет занимать переменная (или тип) во время выполнения программы (уже после оптимизации, которая Вас почему-то беспокоит). 

Увидев 4 для привычной архитектуры (уверен, что у Вас x86 или x86-64) Вы догадаетесь, что это примитивный int.

А что Вас не устраивает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Документация](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/underlying_type/) по `std::underlying_type` утверждает, что:

> The *underlying type* of an `enum` declared with `enum class` is `int` unless a different type is specified on declaration.

В переводе:

> *Базовым типом* перечисления, объявленного как `enum class`, является `int`, пока в объявлении не указан иной тип.